# set text to a spinner include selected item and a constant string

Tags: spinner, settext

I have a Spinner with drop down items: "Meter" & "Ft".
When I choose one of these(Meter or Ft),I want the text in Spinner change to : "Length(Meter)" or "Length(Ft)".

how?